# No if-else branch is entered on certain values

Tags: java

I am have a little trouble with this java homework.  I am still fairly new to this programming work.  I am having trouble making the program do the following: Scientists measure an object’s mass in kilograms and its weight in Newtons. If you know the amount of mass that an object has, you can calculate its weight, in Newtons, with the following formula:

Weight = mass X 9.8

Write a program that asks the user to enter an object’s mass, and then calculate its weight. If the object weighs more than 1000 Newtons, display a message indicating that it is too heavy. If the object weighs less than 10 Newtons, display a message indicating that the object is too light.

this is what I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MassandWeight{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double mass;

        System.out.print("Please enter the object's mass: ");
        mass = keyboard.nextDouble();

        // Convert the mass to weight using the following expression:
        double weight = (mass * 9.8);

        if (weight >= 10 && weight <= 1000)
            System.out.println("The weight of the object is " + weight + ".");

        else if (weight > 1001)
            System.out.println("The object's weight is too heavy.");

        else if (weight < 9)
            System.out.println("The object's weight is too light.");
    }
}
```

so everything works great! and I am really proud of myself for getting this far. however when I enter "1" i get no response back. everything else works great. if you need more information, please let me know. Thank you!!

Comment: What happens if you enter 1.0? And does the same happen if you enter 2?

Comment: Your tilte is not helpful at all!

Comment: 1 * 9.8 = 9.8 but your If is between 10 and 1000. It doesn't enter the if statement. 9.8 is neither >=10 nor <9

Comment: Should use an else instead of an else-if for the last clause so something is guaranteed to happen since this program as is breaks for values 9, 10, 1000 and 1001

Answer (score 5):

You're checking for values of `weight` in (-∞, 9), [10, 1000] and (1001, +∞). This means that you're missing values in [9 and 10) and (1000, 1001]. If you input `1`, the `weight` will be `9.8` and you'll be missing it.

Here's what your `if`s should look like, instead:

```
if (weight >=10 && weight <= 1000) ...      
else if (weight > 1000) ...
else if (weight < 10) ...
```

Comment: oh my gosh, i made such a bad mistake :( thank you for helping me clear this up! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since it's for a homework, I won't give it all out... but check your if/else... maybe put an else at the end so you can see the scenarios that are not caught with your else if.

Comment: You should ether answer to question, or not answer at all. Half answers are not considered answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter **1** then the **weight = (1* 9.8) = 9.8**

you have 3 conditions:

**1- weight >=10 && weight <= 1000**

**2- weight > 1001**

**3- weight < 9**

so **9.8** doesn't match with this conditions

you need `else {}` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Check the last else statement. It does not check if it is less than 10. When the weight is > 9 && < 10, no statement is executed (entering 1 sets the weight to 9.8)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
else if (weight < 9)
```

to

```
else if (weight < 10)
```

and

```
else if (weight > 1001)
```

to

```
else if (weight > 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I write else-if statements like this in ways that *guarantee* an execution of a path. Consider the following:

```
if (weight < 10) {
  // too light
} else if (weight > 1000) {
  // too heavy
} else {
  // just right - this MUST be the case if
  // the previous branches are not selected
}
```

Using an approach like this helps me reduce programming bugs and increase refactorability by *removing duplication* of comparissions. I also find it easier to read.

See [TDWTF: But...Anything Can Happen!](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/ButAnything-Can-Happen!.aspx) for an extreme perversion of duplicating comparisons: the posted code isn't nearly as bad, but in my opinion it suffers from the same fundamental flaw.